# NullPointerException Problem when trying to mock Elastic Search's RestHighLevelClient

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito, resthighlevelclient

I'm facing a NullPointerException during unit testing, when trying to test and mock a `RestHighLevelClient`  inside an `ElasticClient` class:

```
@Configuration
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ElasticClient{

   @Setter
   private RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient;

    @PostConstruct
    public void buildRestHighLevelClient(){

        RestClientBuilder restClientBuilder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(
                "127.0.0.1",
                9200, "http")
        );

        restClientBuilder.setRequestConfigCallback(
                requestConfigBuilder ->
                        requestConfigBuilder
                                .setConnectTimeout(500000)
                                .setSocketTimeout(600000)
                                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(0)
        )
                .setHttpClientConfigCallback(
                        httpClientBuilder ->
                                httpClientBuilder
                                        .setMaxConnPerRoute(2048)
                );

        restHighLevelClient = new RestHighLevelClient(restClientBuilder);
    }

   public boolean isReachable(){
     return restHighLevelClient.ping(RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
   }

}
```

And the test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ElasticClientTest{

@Mock
private RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient;


ElasticClient elasticClient;

@Before
public void init(){

    elasticClient = new ElasticClient();
    elasticClient.setRestHighLevelClient(restHighLevelClient);

}
```

And the NullPointerException is coming from here:

```
    @Test
    public void whenElasticIsPingable_thenReturnTrue() throws IOException{

           when(restHighLevelClient.ping(RequestOptions.DEFAULT)).thenReturn(true);
           Assertions.assertThat(elasticClient.isReachable()).isTrue();
    }
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1764)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1734)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.ping(RestHighLevelClient.java:694)
at com.example.ElasticClientTest.whenElasticIsPingable_thenReturnTrue(ElasticClientTest.java:44)
```

Comment: is this `RestHighLevelClient` Autowired in  `ElasticClient` ?, can you show complete class of `ElasticClient`

Comment: @Deadpool no autowire. Added more details to the class

Comment: [`restHighLevelClient.ping`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/client/rest-high-level/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/client/RestHighLevelClient.java#L719) is a `final` method. Did you enable mockito to handle `final` as mentioned in the [docu](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.1.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#39) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is originated from the fact that the `ping` method in the `RestHighLevelClient` is `final` as can't be mocked regularly.

So, I used the help of [this example](https://www.baeldung.com/intro-to-powermock) about **PowerMock**

And in the final result:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(RestHighLevelClient.class)
public class ElasticClientTest{

ElasticClient elasticClient;

RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient;

@Before
public void init(){

    restHighLevelClient = mock(RestHighLevelClient.class);

    elasticClient = new ElasticClient();
    elasticClient.setRestHighLevelClient(restHighLevelClient);

}


@Test
public void whenElasticIsPingable_thenReturnTrue() throws IOException{

    when(restHighLevelClient.ping(RequestOptions.DEFAULT)).thenReturn(true);

    Assertions.assertThat(elasticClient.isReachable()).isTrue();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a mockito extension for mock a finalized object with these steps:

1. Create a folder called "mockito-extensions" in test resources
   folder.
2. Add a file called "org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker" inside the
   folder.
3. In that file, write "mock-maker-inline"

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
when(restHighLevelClient.ping(eq(RequestOptions.DEFAULT))).thenReturn(true);
```

Comment: With the same stacktrace ? Which `eq` method are you importing ?

Comment: The error is a bit different - `You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing` and `java.lang.NullPointerException: options cannot be null

 at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:228)
 at org.elasticsearch.client.Request.setOptions(Request.java:126)
 at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1761)
 at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1734)
 at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.ping(RestHighLevelClient.java:694)`

Comment: import static org.mockito.Mockito.eq;

Comment: The import statement is OK. Can you please run your test without the `@SpringBootTest` to see if it is the root cause of this problem (I'm not sûre)

Comment: same result when removing the `@SpringBootTest`