# RestHighLevelClient JUnit Testing returns NullPointerException

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, junit

I am currently working on how to test coverage my ElasticSearch Class which implements RestHighLevelClient.  The problem is that it returns null pointer pointing to the RestHighLevelClient.class.  I am new to ES and I don't know where am I going wrong.

Here is my ElasticSearch class:

```
@Service
public class ElasticsearchService {

    @Autowired
    private LoggingService loggingService;

    @Autowired
    private LocationService locationService;

    @Autowired
    private RestHighLevelClient client;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Autowired
    private Utils util;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationProperties prop;

    public String addAtmStatusRecord(ATM atm) throws IOException {
        GeoPoint geoPoint = locationService.getLocation(atm.getTerminalId());

        XContentBuilder builder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder();
        builder.startObject()
            .field("terminalId", atm.getTerminalId())
            .field("atmStatus", "D".equals(atm.getAtmStatus()) ? 1 : 0)
            .field("atmLocation", atm.getAtmLocation())
            .field("errorDescription", atm.getErrorDescription())
            .field("lastTranTime", atm.getLastTranTime())
            .field("lastDevStatTime", atm.getLastDevStatTime())
            .field("errorCode", atm.getErrorCode())
            .field("termBrcode", atm.getTermBrcode())
            .timeField("@timestamp", new Date())
            .latlon("location", geoPoint.getLat(), geoPoint.getLon())
            .endObject();

        IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(prop.getEsIndex(), prop.getEsType(), atm.getTerminalId()).source(builder);
        IndexResponse response = client.index(indexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        loggingService.log(this.getClass().toString(), atm.getTerminalId(), TraceLog.SUCCESSFUL_PUSH_TO_ELASTIC_SEARCH, 
                util.mapToJsonString(atm));

        return response.getResult().name();
    }



    public List<AtmElasticSearchData> searchForOfflineAtmData() throws IOException {
        SearchResponse searchResponse = getAllOfflineAtmData();
        List<SearchHit> searchHits = Arrays.asList(searchResponse.getHits().getHits());
        List<AtmElasticSearchData> listOfAtm = new ArrayList<>();

        for (SearchHit searchHit : searchHits) {
            listOfAtm.add(mapper.readValue(searchHit.getSourceAsString(), AtmElasticSearchData.class));
        }

        return listOfAtm;
    }

    public SearchResponse getAllOfflineAtmData() throws IOException {
        Map<String, Object> queryParam = new HashMap<>();   
        queryParam.put("atmStatus", 1);
        return retrieveElasticSearchData(queryParam);
    }

    public long getAllOfflineAtmCount() throws IOException {
        return getAllOfflineAtmData().getHits().getTotalHits();
    }

    private SearchResponse retrieveElasticSearchData(Map<String, Object> queryParams) throws IOException {
        SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder  = new SearchSourceBuilder();

        queryParams.entrySet().forEach(queryParam -> searchSourceBuilder.query(
                QueryBuilders.termQuery(queryParam.getKey(), queryParam.getValue())));
        searchSourceBuilder.from(0);
        searchSourceBuilder.size(Integer.parseInt(prop.getEsMaxSearchSize()));
        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(prop.getEsIndex())
                .types(prop.getEsType())
                .source(searchSourceBuilder);

        return client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    }
}
```

Here is my test case:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ATMMonitoringApplication.class, initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
public class ElasticsearchServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private ElasticsearchService elasticsearchService;

    @MockBean
    private LoggingService loggingService;

    @MockBean
    private LocationService locationService;

    @MockBean
    private RestHighLevelClient client;

    @MockBean
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @MockBean
    private Utils util;

    @MockBean
    private IndexRequest indexRequest;
    @MockBean IndexResponse indexResponse;

    @Value("${elastic.search.atm.monitoring.index}")
    private String esIndex;

    @Value("${elastic.search.atm.monitoring.type}")
    private String esType;

    private ATM atm;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws ParseException, IOException {

        client = mock(RestHighLevelClient.class);
        indexRequest = mock(IndexRequest.class);
        indexResponse = mock(IndexResponse.class);

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        atm = new ATM();
        atm.setAtmLocation("location");
        atm.setAtmStatus("U");
        atm.setErrorCode("222");
        atm.setErrorDescription("STATUS");
        atm.setLastDevStatTime(null);
        atm.setLastTranTime(null);
        atm.setTerminalId("123");
        atm.setTermBrcode("111");

    }

    @Test
    public void testAddAtmStatusRecordIsNull() throws IOException, NumberFormatException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {

        Mockito.when(locationService.getLocation(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(new GeoPoint(121.00000, 11.9874));
        elasticsearchService.addAtmStatusRecord(atm);
        assertThat(1).isEqualTo(1);
    }
        @Test
    public void testAddAtmStatusRecordAtmIsDown() throws IOException {
        ATM atm = new ATM();
        atm.setAtmStatus("D");
        Mockito.when(locationService.getLocation(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(new GeoPoint(121.00000, 11.9874));
        elasticsearchService.addAtmStatusRecord(atm);
        assertThat(1).isEqualTo(1);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetAllOfflineAtmCount() throws IOException {

        elasticsearchService.getAllOfflineAtmCount();
        assertThat(1).isEqualTo(1);

    }

    @Test
    public void testsearchForOfflineAtmData() throws IOException {

        List<AtmElasticSearchData> atmEsData = new ArrayList<>();
            elasticsearchService.searchForOfflineAtmData();

        assertThat(1).isEqualTo(1);
    }


}
```

My port is already set on 9200 in my app.properties.

Please send me out some help on this.  I really need to resolve this.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you have marked a variable `@MockBean`, why are you again assigning it a mocked object like `client = mock(RestHighLevelClient.class);`?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the methods in RestHighLevelClient are final so cannot be mocked and call actual method and throwing null pointer. Please see this post [NullPointerException Problem when trying to mock Elastic Search's RestHighLevelClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58914298/nullpointerexception-problem-when-trying-to-mock-elastic-searchs-resthighlevelc)